# set different opacity for nested elements

Tags: html, css

I want to make a win7 file exporlor-like effect: the title bar have a opacity less than 1, while the content have no opacity.

Then I tried to combine two elements together to make it:

```
<div id="outer" style="background-color:black;opacity:0.6;padding:30px;position:absolute;width:400px;height:400px;">
    <div id="inner" style="background-color:gray;opacity:1;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to make the `div#outer` have a opacity of 0.8,then make the `div#inner` have no opacity(with opacity=1).

However it seems that this does not work. Since the opacity of `div#outer` will affect that of the `div#inner`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However it seems that this does not work. Since the opacity of div#outer will affect that of the div#inner.

Correct.

---

But if what you want is just a translucent background, setting [RGBA color](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-color/#rgba-color) as `background-color` would meet the needs. Like this:

```
<div id="outer" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);padding:30px;position:absolute;width:400px;height:400px;">
    <div id="inner" style="background-color:gray;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

---

For more infomation, read MDN documents here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color

---

For IE 7 support, I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12588020/90172)(using generated background image files) is an acceptable solution.

Comment: +1, I need to type faster. Also is good to point that opacity will affect the text as well.

Comment: @Rox:Does this support IE7+?

Comment: @hguser at least not for IE 7. But since IE 7 supports png transparency, I think you can use a png with alpha channel as background image. Please follow the link I just added in the answer.

Comment: @Rox:Thanks,I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

The inner div will inherit the opacity of its container.

A cross-browser workaround is to avoid nested elements and use absolute positioning instead. You can see an example here where opacity is applied to the background but the text has an opacity of 1:
http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/Lists/May2010/calendar.aspx?CalendarDate=5%2F5%2F2010

Code sample (two span elements are placed side by side within the main span, the second one is the background that gets the opacity):

```
<span style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <span style="width:100%;height:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;border:1px solid Red;position:absolute;color:Red;font-weight:bold;">
    11:00 AM  Image Capture &amp; ECM Using SharePoint
    </span>
    <span style="display:inline-block;width: 100%;height:100%;background-color:Red;text-align:center;border:1px solid;z-index:-1;filter:alpha(opacity=20);opacity:0.2;font-weight:bold;">
    11:00 AM Image Capture &amp; ECM Using SharePoint
    </span>
</span>
```